# Diseño de producto css c#

Tags: c#, css

Buenas Tardes amigos les comento, estoy desarrollando un catalogo de articulo en c#, entonces tengo la sección de  "Destacados", en el controlador es una simple consulta.

```
public ActionResult getDestacados() {

        var productos = db.MtoProductos.Where(x => x.Destacado == true)
                                       .OrderByDescending(f=>f.Fecha).Take(13).ToList();

        return View(productos);
    }
```

hasta ahí sin problemas, el problema viene en la view cuando diseño con css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el css que estoy ocupando

```css
.snip1423 {
    font-family: 'Oswald', Arial, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 20px 1%;
    min-width: 230px;
    max-width: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;   
}

    .snip1423 * {
        -webkit-box-sizing: padding-box;
        box-sizing: padding-box;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
        transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    }

    .snip1423 img {
        max-width: 100%;
        vertical-align: top;
        position: relative;
    }

    .snip1423 figcaption {
        padding: 20px 15px;
    }

    .snip1423 h3,
    .snip1423 p {
        margin: 0;
    }

    .snip1423 h3 {
        font-size: 1.3em;
        font-weight: 400;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        color: #d8822f;
        /* text-transform: uppercase;*/
    }

    .snip1423 p {
        font-size: 0.9em;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        font-weight: 300;
    }

    .snip1423 .price {
        font-weight: 500;
        font-size: 1.4em;
        line-height: 48px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
    }

        .snip1423 .price s {
            margin-right: 5px;
            opacity: 0.5;
            font-size: 0.9em;
        }

    .snip1423 i {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
        width: 56px;
        line-height: 56px;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #666666;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 1.6em;
        border: 4px solid #ffffff;
    }

    .snip1423 a {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .snip1423:hover,
    .snip1423.hover {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
        transform: translateY(-5px);
    }

        .snip1423:hover i,
        .snip1423.hover i {
            background-color: #2980b9;
        }
```

este es el codigo de la vista `

```
<div class="container">

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <figure class="snip1423 wow zoomIn animated" data-wow-delay="0ms" data-wow-duration="1500ms" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 1500ms; animation-delay: 0ms; animation-name: zoomIn;">
            <img src="@Url.Content(@item.Ruta)" />
            <figcaption>
                <h3>@item.Titulo</h3>
                <p>@item.Descripcion</p>
                <div class="price">
                    $@if (@item.Oferta == true)
                    {<s>$@item.Precio</s>@item.PrecioOferta}
                else
                {@item.Precio}
                </div>
            </figcaption><i class="ion-android-cart"></i>
            <a href="#"></a>
        </figure>
    }
</div>
```

`

creen que puedan echarme una mano.

muchas gracias.

Comment: estas seguro que es un problema del css, no sera en como generas el html con los datos del producto?

Comment: Me imagino que estas usando un framework, por ejemplo Bootstrap, Será que es posible de otorgarnos el código de la vista (html)

Comment: Acá intervienen un montón de variable, por ejemplo ¿Como es el html? ¿Cada fila está anidando 3 opciones o no hay filas determinadas por etiquetas? o ¿Cada producto tiene posición absoluta? ¿Usas algún framework?

Comment: Hola Horacio, lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] y comparte el código html generado para que podamos reproducir el problema.

Answer (score 0):

el problema parece ser el texto que hace que cambien el tamaño los H3 y los párrafos dentro de la descripción.

Puedes intentar con algo como esto:

```
    .snip1423 p {
        font-size: 0.9em;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        font-weight: 300;
        height: 50px; /*le das un alto predefinido*/
    }

    .snip1423 h3 {
        font-size: 1.3em;
        font-weight: 400;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        color: #d8822f;
        height:50px;
        /* text-transform: uppercase;*/
    }
```

Espero te pueda ayudar.